# List and delete pending update requests in Smartsheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

I've been able to **Create Update Request** with both Postman and the Smartsheet Python SDK, but I can't find a method in the API documentation to list pending update requests or delete pending update requests. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for managing pending update requests is not yet available in the API.  We are working on adding it and hope to have it available soon (in the next month or so).  Please stay tuned and thank you for your patience.